# Read JSON File: I want to read the content of external JSON file and use as input

Tags: json

JSON File:
I want to read the content of external JSON file

```
{
    "article": {
        "article_doi": "13.032020/11032020",
        "sage_article_id": 1,
        "peer_review_id":"PRV1",
        "article_title": "WF2-only with CBP",
        "journal_id": "HIJ",
        "article_type": "Article",
        "author_role": "Author",
        "submission_date": "2020-03-13",
        "article_acceptance_date": "2020-03-13",
        "SMART_entry_date": "2020-03-12",
        "first_article_export_date": "2020-03-13",
        "subscription_published_date": "",
        "oa_published_date":""
    },
    "authors": [
        { 
            "email": "raman.kumar@aptaracorp.com",
            "title": "",
            "first_name": "Raman",
            "last_name": "Kumar",
            "country_code": "AUS",
            "orcid": "",
            "institution_ringgold_id": "4615",
            "institution_ringgold_name": "Imperial College London",
            "author_sequence_number": 1,
            "corresponding_author": true
        },
        {
            "email": "authorname2@aptaracorp.com",
            "title": "",
            "first_name": "Prateek",
            "last_name": "Sharma",
            "country_code": "AUS",
            "orcid": "",
            "institution_ringgold_id": "",
            "institution_ringgold_name": "",
            "author_sequence_number": 2,
            "corresponding_author": false
        }
    ],
    "oa_requester": {
        "email": "pavan.kumar@aptaracorp.com",
        "title": "",
        "first_name": "Pavan",
        "last_name": "Kumar",
        "organisation": "Requestor Organisation",
        "oa_requested_date": "2018-10-17"
    },  
    "societies": [
        {
            "society_name": "S1",
            "society_membership_number":"SMN1"
        },
        {
            "society_name": "S2",
            "society_membership_number":"SMN2"
        }
    ], 
    "article_process_info": {       

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    File inFile = new File("TestData.json");
           StringBuilder targetString = new StringBuilder();
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(inFile);
                   // @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                   String s= null;
                    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                       targetString.append(s);                             
                    }
                    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("request_json"));
                    body.sendKeys(targetString);
                 String sCurrentLine=null;
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);                    

                   }
```

Comment: Not able to send all json's data.